# Method to change elements inside struct in C++?

Tags: c++, methods, struct

I have a structure with 2 fields which have a value. I would like to implement a method that changes the values of the fields. I did this with the following code, but it is not correct. I would like to ask how can I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct CPerson {
    const char* name = "Ivan";
    const char* gender = "Male";

};
void SetName(const char* szName) {
    //what to write here?
    *name = *szname;
}
```

Comment: Please use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) rather than `char *`.

Comment: I think, you must look at the C++ Data Structures. I recommend read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/) blog

Comment: @G.M.: Sometimes an [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

A struct works like a class, the only difference is that all inside the struct is public by default.

So you can (and in this case you have to) declare setName inside the struct

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
void SetName(CPerson& p, const char* szName) {
    p.name = szName;
}
```

Be careful though, `szName` argument may be pointing to an array whose lifetime may end before the lifetime of `CPerson::name` ends. That makes `CPerson::name` an invalid pointer.

Comment: name is not defined in SetName. Needs to be a member function

Comment: However it says identifier name (from the structure) is not defined? I want to change the name field of the declared strucuture

Comment: @A.Dimitrov You need to pass `Person` object into the function.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make it a member function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct CPerson {
    const char* name = "Ivan";
    const char* gender = "Male";


   void SetName(const char* szName) {
    //what to write here?
    name = szname;
}
};
```

that code is still wrong as its just juggling pointers. You should use std::string to store strings. But at least the code will compile;

Comment: i'm not the downvoter but I think trying to change a const pointer once it has been initialized may not work so well.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to implement a method that changes the values of the fields.

I wouldn't be so certain you should do that.

You see, the fields of a struct are, by default, publicly-accessible - which means anyone can change them, method or no method. Why bother writing such a method? Isn't it redundant?

If you had a *class* instead of a struct, or if you had set your field access to `protected` or `private`, then it makes sense to have a method for setting field value, e.g.:

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

struct Person {
protected:
    std::string name = "Ivan";
    std::string gender = "Male";

public:
   void changeName(std::string_view new_name) {
       name = new_name;
   }
};
```

(`string_view` is new in C++17; before that, you could use  `const std::string&`).

But even then it's not always a good idea to have that. Also, in this struct of yours, there's a default name and gender, without a good reason. Instead of both these things, you might make the struct immutable:

```
#include <string>

struct Person {
    const std::string name;
    const std::string gender;
};
```

which, for many applications, makes sense (e.g. if you get this from some database, rather than tracking a person's name and gender throughout their lives).